# Writing a plugin to make a query using the response of another query in elasticsearch

Tags: java, rest, maven, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

> What are you trying to do?

I want to:

1. Make a geo-query to get device-IDs in a location - in device-location index.
2. Use the list of device-IDs to get device logs - in device-logs index.

---

> What have you tried so far?

I am building this using Maven. Here is the `plugin-security.policy`:

```
grant {  
    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "setFactory";
};
```

#### Failed solution 1

##### Making web-request in Elasticsearch

The idea was to make 2 queries by calling Elasticsearch API from itself.

```java
        HttpClient client2 = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
        HttpRequest request2 = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
             .uri(URI.create("http://localhost:9200"))
             .build();
        
        HttpResponse<String> res = client2.sendAsync(request2, BodyHandlers.ofString()).join();
```

Failed because of security issues. Even tried making another thread also with `AccessController.doPriviledged()` but same issue.

```
[2022-06-09T16:57:27,506][ERROR][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [masterNode] uncaught exception in thread [Thread-3]
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("org.elasticsearch.secure_sm.ThreadPermission" "modifyArbitraryThreadGroup")
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:332) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:347) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:874) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:841) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:510) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1773) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) [?:?]
        at jdk.internal.misc.InnocuousThread.run(InnocuousThread.java:162) ~[?:?]
```

#### Failed solution 2

##### Directly calling RestSearchAction (Making search query programmatically)

I found no documentation on how to make plugins for elasticsearch or how to call elasticsearch's functions programmatically.
So dug right into the code on GitHub and found this:

```java
public class RestSearchAction extends BaseRestHandler {
```

and this:

```java
public class SearchRequest extends ActionRequest implements IndicesRequest.Replaceable, Rewriteable<SearchRequest> {
```

But I cannot figure out how to call any of them, I imagine using something like:

```java
String searchResult = SearchQuery("/index/_search",queryString);
```

But I have a good feeling it wouldn't be that simple :)
Elasticsearch Version: 8.1.3

### ANY help AT ALL is appreciated. Please do comment if you need more info.

***References"***

1. RestSearchAction Class: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/rest/action/search/RestSearchAction.java
2. SearchRequest Class: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/action/search/SearchRequest.java

Comment: Why do you need a plugin for such a highly specific need? Why not simply send those two queries from your application?

Comment: @Val the guys on the other side want this to happen in one query and it has come to me as a requirement. The only other solution I can think of is an API Gateway for just 1 route, which I feel is a really bad solution. Any other thoughts?